Motorola xoom Firmware
I have a Motorola Xoom Tablet I bought new years ago. After Moving I found it aqain. It not only still works great, but the battery still works as well. I had quit using it because after android version 4.1.2, there were no more updates and google play store quit working. It really is a shame to have such a nice tablet, that works so well (physically) be useless due to software version.
I am looking to see if anyone has an update that will work on the Motorola Xoom. At this point it is basically a brick anyway so I am losing nothing by trying something.

You are not looking for an update (because updates have to be signed by Motorola and if it would exist it would be downloadable). The only way to you is unlock the bootloader and install a custom ROM (Android system built by other users) that was developed for Motorola Xoom tablet. Not sure if you will find one and if it is still after that time. See also How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version
